# Localstack publish-batch payload invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I keep getting this payload structure error when debugging an event-driven lambda with Localstack.

```
localstack  | > ERROR Lambda runtime invoke{requestId="c2931325-f6a5-1b7b-a65c-1331d57dfd43" xrayTraceId="Root=1-dc99d00f-c079a84d433534434534ef0d;Parent=91ed514f1e5c03b2;Sampled=1"}: Failed to process msg 7e4956dc-b354-4f5c-8dc1-8b24c8df5feb, missing field `event`
```

This is the payload:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "MSG000000",
        "Message": "{\n    \"event\": \"starred\",\n    \"action\": \"CREATE\",\n    \"data\": {\n        \"brand\": \"viaplay\",\n        \"type\": \"starred\",\n        \"profileId\": \"profile000\",\n        \"mediaGuid\": \"myguid\",\n        \"metadata\": \"mymetadata\"\n    }\n}",
        "Subject": "Test sns",
        "MessageStructure": "String",
        "MessageAttributes": {
            "brand": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": "viaplay"
            },
            "type": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": "starred"
            },
            "action": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": "CREATE"
            },
            "schema": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": "UPMS#1"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'm trying to follow the official documentation [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.4.18/reference/sns/publish-batch.html), but there's no straightforward example of how the payload should be structured for every subscription protocol. In my case, it's an SQS.

Any pointers?